# Group by one column in select list-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Is their a way to group by a.MEMB? I have researched it and found some ways around it but can't seem to get it to work. I'm not to interested in whats in other coolumns but I do need to display them in the results.

```
 ;with main as (SELECT a.MEMB
   , ta.DRAW
   , ta.foc
   , a.ENTRY
  , tc.DESCRIP

   FROM a with (nolock)
          inner join  tal      
   inner join  ta      
         inner join tc        
  WHERE a.ENTRY between @start and @end
   and a.TRAN != 0
   and tc.TRANN=a.TRANN
   and tc.TRANT=a.TRANT  
)
```

Comment: @RajeshChamarthi: the fact that the statement termination character is at the beginning of the statement and the `nolock` seems to indicate SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to partition the data. However your query won't currently work as you are missing joins

```
;with main as 
(SELECT a.MEMB, ta.DRAW, ta.foc, a.ENTRY, tc.DESCRIP,
        row_number() over (partition by a.MEMB order by a.Memb) rn
 FROM a with (nolock) 
 inner join  tal on ...
 inner join  ta  on ...     
 inner join tc     on    tc.TRANN=a.TRANN 
     and tc.TRANT=a.TRANT   
  WHERE a.ENTRY between @start and @end 
   and a.TRAN != 0 
) 
    select * from main where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks after reworking it a bit I got it to work with this solution thanks. Kept getting columns but be in aggregate but didn't want to do that.